# Workflow with package-lock.json

Tags: javascript, npm, workflow

Ok so I have an npm project at my work that a bunch of us are working on. It has dependencies on 'lodash' and 'jquery'.

I do an `>npm install`, and it pulls down my deps. Then I bundle it.

That creates a 'package-lock.json' on my system.

Now another developer adds a new dependency on 'moment'.

He does a `>npm install -S moment`.

That adds it to his package.json, and he checks that in. We don't check in the package-lock.json.

Now I do a '`git pull`' and get the new package.json.

Now I do `>npm install`, BUT because I have my own package-lock.json, it doesnt install 'moment' for me. So now I have to:

```
>rm package-lock.json
>npm install
```

And now I have 'moment'. Seems like this package-lock.json isn't really helping my workflow. Could I get an explanation of how this should work for developers on a day-to-day basis, if we are all developing on a common npm module?

Comment: Same here. In my project we are developing many private modules which are constantly bumped to newer versions and published (bug fixes, api changes etc...). We'd always like to get the latest versions of all the packages (including the nested ones) of all the modules in `package.json`. The `package-lock.json` gives us some trouble with nested dependencies since those aren't updated anymore. I know it is encouraged to use `package-lock` but it does not help our workflow. Right now we are deleting it before `npm i` and we are not commit it.Any way you can `npm config set package-lock false`

Comment: Hello, wich NPM version are you using ? I'm in a similar case with NPM 5.3+ and it works like a charm. However you could suggest to "another developer" to check compatibility after `>npm install -S moment` with `npm prune && npm i` before to push it's package-lock.json

Answer (score 2):

The [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) states:

> This file is intended to be committed into source repositories

So your workflow might be as follows:

- First, you commit your `package-lock.json` after you've done an initial `npm install`.
- Another developer pulls your changes, including the lockfile.
- Then they do `npm install moment`, which makes updates to both `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. The developer pushes a commit with these changes.
- Now you pull their changes and do `npm install`. It should install `moment` for you as well. Furthermore, you both now have exactly the same version of `moment` and its dependencies installed - even if in the time between their and your installs, an update to some dependency was released (that is permitted in your `package.json`).

#### Merge conflicts

It all gets messy when both of you have installed new dependencies in parallel and then have a conflict in the `package-lock.json`. This file may be a huge and quite a pain to merge manually. [The recommended](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18007#issuecomment-401427694) way for dealing with it is to manually resolve conflicts in `package.json` and then let `npm install` merge changes to the `package.lock` file. Alternatively, the `npm-merge-driver` package was suggested.

Comment: `npm -S momewnt` is an unknown command. One has to use [npm-ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci), which uses the versions of `package-lock.json` instead of `package.json`. Just execute `npm ci`. It was introduced in [v.5.7.0](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171139955345/v570).